# Best method to create rare items on a minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server

In a Minecraft server I play on, we're trying to figure out a way to create items on our server that would be found through out our server randomly. We want to create these items with effects/special abilities. We also want a way to distribute them by either randomly placing them through out the world, but we only want a defined number of them to be distributed. We also, if possible, want them to be given to users when they get an achievement.

The kind of answers I'm looking for are ...

- NBT editor bukkit plugins (Hopefully ones that work with Permissions EX)
- Achievement Plugins
- Bungee suit/Essential

Also, our server runs on MySQL and I am trying to find plugins that work with that.

Comment: Why can't you go around the world and place these items manually?

Answer (score 1):

For an achievement plugin, you can try [this](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/lolmewnachievements/) one. It allows you to create your own achievements and allows you to give rewards as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mod found [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/2031111-172-lucky-block-drops-items-spawns-mobs-structures-and-more/), that is around the same idea you have, it's called Lucky Block. Essentially, you can make lucky blocks appear randomly or manually placed with customization effects, items, etc. I'm not sure about the achievment aspect, but if you can find a way to simply input a command once an achievement has "Been Unlocked" you can place a Lucky Block in their inventory. I have used this mod and it seems to work quite well and is pretty flexible.